# When scrolling add a new class when the new right element is fully visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to a create a timeline box with scroll that has overflown items. When scrolling all items fully visible should get the visible class and whenever a new item becomes fully visible should get the visible class. Im missing some math or logic here, to make it accurate. Any tips or alternative methods would be very helpful.

**Codepen: https://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/BaKZgoX**

```
<div id="wrapper" class="history">
  <div class="history-inner">
    <div class="item i1 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i3 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i4"></div>
    <div class="item i5"></div>
    <div class="item i6 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i7"></div>
    <div class="item i8"></div>
    <div class="item i9"></div>
    <div class="item i10 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i11"></div>
    <div class="item i12"></div>
    <div class="item i13"></div>
    <div class="item i14 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i15"></div>
    <div class="item i16 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i17"></div>
    <div class="item i18"></div>
    <div class="item i19 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i20"></div>
    <div class="item i21 wide"></div>
    <div class="item i22"></div>
    <div class="item i23"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.history {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.history-inner {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.item {
  width:120px;
  height:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background: #777;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  &.wide {
    width:170px;
  }
  &.visible {
    background: green !important;
  }
}
.item:nth-child(even){
  background: #666;
}
```

js

```
  var historyW = $('.history').outerWidth();
  var historyInnerW = $('.history-inner').outerWidth();
  var currentHiddenItem = historyW + 5; // bigger than history
  var historyPxScr = $('.history').scrollLeft();
  var entryNum = 1;
  var itemMargin = 0;

  $('.history').on('resize scroll', function() {
    historyW = $('.history').outerWidth();
    historyPxScr = $('.history').scrollLeft();
    console.log( historyW + historyPxScr + ' sum');
    console.log( currentHiddenItem + ' curr');
    // console.log( historyInnerW + ' iii');
    if ( historyW + historyPxScr < currentHiddenItem - itemMargin) {
      $('.item.i'+entryNum).addClass('visible');
    } else {
      currentHiddenItem += $('.item.i'+entryNum).outerWidth();
      itemMargin = $('.item.i'+entryNum).outerWidth();
      //console.log(itemMargin + 'IM');
      entryNum += 1;
      console.log(entryNum);
      console.log(currentHiddenItem);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this, tried to do it in the jQuery way ;-).

```js
var isFullyVisible = function(elem) {
  return elem.getBoundingClientRect().right - window.innerWidth < 0;
}

var checkItemVisibility = function () {
  $('.history .item').each(function (index, elem) {
     if (isFullyVisible(elem)) {
       $(elem).addClass('visible');
     } else {
       $(elem).removeClass('visible');
     }
   });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkItemVisibility();
  $('.history').on('scroll', checkItemVisibility);
});
```

Tested this code in your codepen and it worked.

Comment: `Tested this code in your codepen and it worked.` - can you attach a link to working codepen?